# Creating a HTML button to Delete Rows in Huge project

Tags: php, sql, database

I got a project that uses controllers and Views.

Inside my index file under shares/index.php there is the following code:

```
<div>
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in'])) : ?>
    <a class="btn btn-success btn-share" href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>shares/add">Share Something</a>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php foreach($viewmodel as $item) : ?>

        <div class="well">
            <h3><?php echo $item['title']; ?></h3>
            <small><?php echo $item['create_date']; ?></small>
            <hr />
            <p><?php echo $item['body']; ?></p>
            <br />
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="<?php echo $item['link']; ?>" target="_blank">Go To Website</a>


        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

I need to create a button below the other button that allows me to delete all posts made by the logged in user at that given time. the user is given a user ID of 1

***Extra code to understand project:***

***Config.php***

```
<?php

// Define DB Params
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "");
define("DB_NAME", "shareboard");

// Define URL
define("ROOT_PATH", "/shareboard/");
define("ROOT_URL", "http://localhost/shareboard/");
```

***Index.php***

```
<?php
// Start Session
session_start();

// Include Config
require('config.php');

require('classes/Messages.php');
require('classes/Bootstrap.php');
require('classes/Controller.php');
require('classes/Model.php');

require('controllers/home.php');;
require('controllers/shares.php');
require('controllers/users.php');

require('models/home.php');
require('models/share.php');
require('models/user.php');

$bootstrap = new Bootstrap($_GET);
$controller = $bootstrap->createController();
if($controller){
    $controller->executeAction();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow .. With this much code, there is very small change someone will answer your post. .. please try to provide only the neccessary part of your code/problem .. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Agree with @nakashu. Try to narrow down your problem.

Comment: I know , theres a headline for extra code i wanted to be precise sorry

Comment: I updated it :) and deleted some code